# neural net output values

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to train a neuralnet in R. As of now my dataset has 12 inputs and 1 output variable. My output function is the default logistic function. The inputs however are continuous variables and some are simple flags. I want the output to be in a range of [0,1] but the output I am getting is quite varied. 
Also, since the output activation function is a sigmoidal(logistic) function why is this even happening?
I can try logistic regression but I believe my hypotheses are non linear and logistic might not give me a proper fit.

Thanks in advance
Suraj

Comment: Can you post some data?

Comment: Yes, post some data, but please also along with the code you tried.